# Highlight overlapping date ranges individually

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to highlight overlapping date ranges individually for each person in Excel.

So far I came up with this formula:

[image]

```
=SUMMENPRODUKT(($D3<=$E$3:$E$10000)*($E3>=$D$3:$D$10000))>1
```

But I have trouble to highlight only those rows where a given person, for example Jeff, has overlapping date ranges.

Comment: If you're up to doing some VBA instead of just conditional formatting, I would just run a `for` loop over `Range("C6:C12")` (use `offset(0,1)` to refer to column `D`) checking to see if any given start or end date falls in between the dates you're currently considering. You would need to make an exception for your current row, something like `If currentcell.address=considerationcell.address Then _ Next _ End If`.

Comment: I posted an answer, but then was not sure if I understood the question. Do you mean you want to choose one person (Jeff) and highlight only their entries (i.e. just row 6 not row 9), or only highlight Jeff if he occurs twice with overlapping dates?

Comment: Your question would benefit from a more explicit explanation of what you want highlighted. Show us a few cases where you expect rows to be highlighted, and explain why. For example, I can't tell in your image why Thomas's entry is not highlighted, as it overlaps with Jeff's timeframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-VBA

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($D$6:$D$12,">="&$C6,$C$6:$C$12,"<="&$D6)>1,$B6="Jeff")
```

or referring to whole of columns C & D

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($D:$D,">="&$C6,$C:$C,"<="&$D6)>1,$B6="Jeff")
```

referring to cells in image and applying conditional formatting to cells A6:D12

(if what you mean is to highlight only Jeff if he has overlapping ranges with anyone)

OR

```
=COUNTIFS($D$6:$D$12,">="&$C6,$C$6:$C$12,"<="&$D6,$B$6:$B$12,$B6)>1
```

or referring to whole of columns B, C & D

```
=COUNTIFS($D:$D,">="&$C6,$C:$C,"<="&$D6,$B:$B,$B6)>1
```

(if what you mean is to highlight anyone who overlaps with himself)

It's usually better to use COUNTIFS with this kind of problem if possible than an array-type solution  using SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: Thank you, Tom! Is it correct to assume that the second formula that uses `COUNTIFS` marks all overlapping date ranges with himself except one? So that if I have Jeff and Jeff has three overlapping date ranges two are highlighted?

Comment: Sorry for slow reply. No, it will highlight all date ranges where he overlaps with himself.

Comment: No problem! :) But the second formula seems to be off in some cases. Can't say why though at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Using VBA

```
Dim currentcell, considerationcell as Range
For each currentcell in Range("C6:C12")
    For each considerationcell in Range("C6:C12")
        If currentcell.Address=considerationcell.Address Then
            GoTo nextiteration
        End If
        If currentcell >= considerationcell and currentcell <= considerationcell.Offset(0,1) Then
            Range(considerationcell.Offset(0,-2), considerationcell.Offset(0,1)).Interior.Color = RGB(111,111,111)
        End If
        If currentcell.Offset(0,1) >= considerationcell and currentcell.Offset(0,1) <= considerationcell.Offset(0,1) Then
            Range(considerationcell.Offset(0,-2), considerationcell.Offset(0,1)).Interior.Color = RGB(111,111,111)
        End If
nextiteration:
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks very promising. :) Unfortunately, I get an error message when I execute the code: `Next without For`. Can you help me here?

Comment: Sorry about that. I haven't skipped out of a for loop like that in VBA before and assumed Next would work like that, but apparently not. This update should work now (tested it myself).

Comment: I tested it, and though it is nice *working* solution to my problem, it seems a little computationally wasteful for the amount of data I have. As a result, I hope it is OK with you if I accept Tom's answer.